# php Mysql CREATE TABLE If does't exist only once

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I only want to create the table once if it doesn't exist. Will this code create a new table every time? If yes, how do I prevent it?

```
$queryCreateUsersTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EmailList (
  `ListName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ID` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ConfirmedEmail` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Subscribed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;";

if(!$conn->query($queryCreateUsersTable))
{
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $dbConnection->errno . ") " . $dbConnection->error;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it's too trivial! The OP only had to run it twice to find out!

Comment: It makes little sense to do that in the every-day executed code: you'll do a lot of useless `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` queries, and it also means that the PHP user have the rights to do so (very hazardous). You should do it in a "initialization" area.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` means it will only create the table if it is not present.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as what `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` means. Create a table if table does not exist.

Therefore, no it does not.